# how to ping & use specific network card

Tags: 11.10, networking, ping

> i have 3 network cards , 1 Lan (wired) , 1 wireless network card & 1 is wireless usb
>
> how do i ping from specific network card ?
>
> & how do i use specific network card for specific application

example

```
i want to ping google from wlan0
```

example for specific application

```
i want to use firefox or transmission from wan1
```

## UPDATED

Lan ip 192.168.0.2 > Working Properly 
[image]

Wlan1 ip 192.168.0.3

[image]

```
pin -I wlan1 google.com
```

## UPDATE

Try pasting the output of route -n and/or ip route. Seems to me that the wlan1 interface hasn't a valid gateway configured. –@MrShunz

```
one@onezero:~$ route -n 
Kernel IP routing table
Destination     Gateway         Genmask         Flags Metric Ref    Use Iface
0.0.0.0         192.168.0.1     0.0.0.0         UG    0      0        0 eth0
169.254.0.0     0.0.0.0         255.255.0.0     U     1000   0        0 eth0
172.16.221.0    0.0.0.0         255.255.255.0   U     0      0        0 vmnet8
192.168.0.0     0.0.0.0         255.255.255.0   U     1      0        0 eth0
192.168.0.0     0.0.0.0         255.255.255.0   U     2      0        0 wlan1
192.168.48.0    0.0.0.0         255.255.255.0   U     0      0        0 vmnet1
one@onezero:~$ ip route
default via 192.168.0.1 dev eth0  proto static 
169.254.0.0/16 dev eth0  scope link  metric 1000 
172.16.221.0/24 dev vmnet8  proto kernel  scope link  src 172.16.221.1 
192.168.0.0/24 dev eth0  proto kernel  scope link  src 192.168.0.2  metric 1 
192.168.0.0/24 dev wlan1  proto kernel  scope link  src 192.168.0.3  metric 2 
192.168.48.0/24 dev vmnet1  proto kernel  scope link  src 192.168.48.1
```

Comment: Try pasting the output of `route -n` and/or `ip route`. Seems to me that the wlan1 interface hasn't a valid gateway configured.

Comment: @MrShunz > UPDATED

Comment: i updated my answer accordingly

Answer (score 13, accepted):

`ping` has a specific switch to set source interface: `-I`. As found in the manpage:

```
 -I interface address
          Set source address to specified interface address. Argument may be  numeric  
          IP  address  or  name  of device.
          When pinging IPv6 link-local address this option is required.
```

As an example

```
$ ping -I wlan0 8.8.8.8
```

ping 8.8.8.8 through wlan0 interface.

Forcing an interface for a specific application needs some more work. You can find a solution [in this superuser.com question](https://superuser.com/questions/241178/how-to-use-different-network-interfaces-for-different-processes) and in [this article](http://daniel-lange.com/archives/53-Binding-applications-to-a-specific-IP.html) linked in the answer.

**UPDATE**

The methods i exposed in this answer show how to force ping to use a specific interface. And links to some articles on how to force a generic program to use a specific interface.

Now, for all this to work, you have to configure some "advanced" routing. As you can see from the output of `route -n` you have multiple networks, but only ONE gateway to the Internet. That is **good**, as multiple gateway routing is quite an *advanced topic* and somewhat difficult to handle well.

This goes beyond what you asked in the original question. I suggest you to post a new question here or on [Server Fault](https://serverfault.com/) asking how to configure and manage multiple internet gateways on multiple network interfaces.

Or, better yet, try googling it ;) Also check the [LARTC site](http://lartc.org/) for advanced linux routing configurations.

Comment: From 192.168.0.8 icmp_seq=2 Destination Host Unreachable

Comment: @OneZero That means you cannot reach destination. Is `192.168.0.8` the address of wlan0? Does exists a gateway configured for that interface?

Comment: > Updated changed the ip 8 to 3 of wlan static ..