# How can I ping from specific network card on Ubuntu v16.04 LTS?

Tags: networking, ping

This is my **network config** on my laptop running Ubuntu v16.04.3 LTS:

```
luis@Hipatio:~$ ifconfig
enp2s0    Link encap:Ethernet  direcciónHW 68:f7:28:d2:a4:ce
          Direc. inet:192.168.11.119  Difus.:192.168.11.255  Másc:255.255.255.0
          Dirección inet6: fe80::6af7:28ff:fed2:a4ce/64 Alcance:Enlace
          ACTIVO DIFUSIÓN FUNCIONANDO MULTICAST  MTU:1500  Métrica:1
          Paquetes RX:1330 errores:0 perdidos:0 overruns:0 frame:0
          Paquetes TX:915 errores:0 perdidos:0 overruns:0 carrier:0
          colisiones:0 long.colaTX:1000
          Bytes RX:121080 (121.0 KB)  TX bytes:85100 (85.1 KB)

enx3c18a00b753d Link encap:Ethernet  direcciónHW 3c:18:a0:0b:75:3d
          Direc. inet:192.168.11.2  Difus.:192.168.11.255  Másc:255.255.255.0
          Dirección inet6: fe80::4c9d:de01:a97a:fd42/64 Alcance:Enlace
          ACTIVO DIFUSIÓN FUNCIONANDO MULTICAST  MTU:1500  Métrica:1
          Paquetes RX:10 errores:0 perdidos:0 overruns:0 frame:0
          Paquetes TX:38 errores:0 perdidos:0 overruns:0 carrier:0
          colisiones:0 long.colaTX:1000
          Bytes RX:2203 (2.2 KB)  TX bytes:5468 (5.4 KB)

lo        Link encap:Bucle local
          Direc. inet:127.0.0.1  Másc:255.0.0.0
          Dirección inet6: ::1/128 Alcance:Anfitrión
          ACTIVO BUCLE FUNCIONANDO  MTU:65536  Métrica:1
          Paquetes RX:24 errores:0 perdidos:0 overruns:0 frame:0
          Paquetes TX:24 errores:0 perdidos:0 overruns:0 carrier:0
          colisiones:0 long.colaTX:1
          Bytes RX:1925 (1.9 KB)  TX bytes:1925 (1.9 KB)
```

**How can I ping**, say, Internet (`8.8.8.8`), from second interface (`enx3c18a00b753d`) ?

Tested **failing**:

```
luis@Hipatio:~$ ping -I enx3c18a00b753d -c 5 8.8.8.8
PING 8.8.8.8 (8.8.8.8) from 192.168.22.51 enx3c18a00b753d: 56(84) bytes of data.

--- 8.8.8.8 ping statistics ---
5 packets transmitted, 0 received, 100% packet loss, time 3999ms
```

**Main adapter** works OK:

```
luis@Hipatio:~$ ping -I enp2s0 -c 5 8.8.8.8
PING 8.8.8.8 (8.8.8.8) from 192.168.11.119 enp2s0: 56(84) bytes of data.
64 bytes from 8.8.8.8: icmp_seq=1 ttl=55 time=51.6 ms
64 bytes from 8.8.8.8: icmp_seq=2 ttl=55 time=52.9 ms
64 bytes from 8.8.8.8: icmp_seq=3 ttl=55 time=50.9 ms
64 bytes from 8.8.8.8: icmp_seq=4 ttl=55 time=50.8 ms
64 bytes from 8.8.8.8: icmp_seq=5 ttl=55 time=51.0 ms

--- 8.8.8.8 ping statistics ---
5 packets transmitted, 5 received, 0% packet loss, time 4005ms
rtt min/avg/max/mdev = 50.812/51.498/52.995/0.826 ms
luis@Hipatio:~$ ping -c 5 8.8.8.8
PING 8.8.8.8 (8.8.8.8) 56(84) bytes of data.
64 bytes from 8.8.8.8: icmp_seq=1 ttl=51 time=57.9 ms
64 bytes from 8.8.8.8: icmp_seq=2 ttl=51 time=57.0 ms
64 bytes from 8.8.8.8: icmp_seq=3 ttl=51 time=57.0 ms
64 bytes from 8.8.8.8: icmp_seq=4 ttl=51 time=57.1 ms
64 bytes from 8.8.8.8: icmp_seq=5 ttl=51 time=57.6 ms
```

This is my **routing table**:

```
luis@Hipatio:~$ sudo route
Tabla de rutas IP del núcleo
Destino         Pasarela        Genmask         Indic Métric Ref    Uso Interfaz
default         Router-         0.0.0.0         UG    0      0        0 enp2s0
default         192.168.22.1    0.0.0.0         UG    100    0        0 enx3c18a00b753d
link-local      *               255.255.0.0     U     1000   0        0 enp2s0
192.168.11.0    *               255.255.255.0   U     0      0        0 enp2s0
192.168.22.0    *               255.255.255.0   U     100    0        0 enx3c18a00b753d
```

**Further notes**:

- This pinging method worked on **v14.04**. Maybe I misconfigured something.
- This pinging method **works on Kali** Linux v2.
- This answer [here](https://askubuntu.com/a/99425/109008) is near to answer, but stops at "google for it".

Answer (score 0):

Try `ip route get 8.8.8.8 from 192.168.22.51` to check your routing table. It may say `enp2s0`.

Comment: Indeed. It does. So?

Comment: Need to setup source routing. http://www.tldp.org/HOWTO/Adv-Routing-HOWTO/lartc.rpdb.multiple-links.html may help you.